# Where to get implementations of Timeouts methods?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to understand how methods - `implicitlyWait`, `setScriptTimeout` and `pageLoadTimeout` of `Timeouts` interface are implemented. Where can I find their implementations?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.31.0/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java

Comment: There is no implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

These are located under *support/ui/* of GitHub public repository

GitHub direct link is [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/bcb1720c6f7f1e98d97dae15eadb576f65eb1094/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui)

And, few [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/bcb1720c6f7f1e98d97dae15eadb576f65eb1094/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium)